# Power Needed For Bluetooth Transmission

Tags: power, bluetooth, low-power

I'm developing a project that has a bluetooth module transmit to an android phone. The project is extremely power limited (it's energy harvesting) and I'm wondering how much power am I looking at to transmit Bluetooth data?

The bluetooth module will be getting sensor data and transmitting that data to a phone about 10 feet away, ideally whenever the user calls for it, but can limit it to maybe every 30 minutes minimum wait.

Comment: How far are you transmitting?

Comment: about 10-15 feet

Answer (score 5):

It will depend on the bluetooth module you've chosen and how busy it is in your application. The [Raytheon BC04 module](http://www.taiwantrade.com.tw/resources/member/276716/productcatalog/2e31e3a9-8bcb-4543-8813-d1e6b56d9b4b_BTM160&170%20DataSheet.pdf) is fairly typical:

> ```
> Deep sleep  40uA 
> ACL 40ms sniff  2.4mA 
> SCO connection HV1  39mA 
> Tx burst +4dBm  58mA
> ```

For an energy harvesting application, Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth Smart) is likely to give you better results.

Comment: That's a lot of current for "deep" sleep.

Comment: Bluetooth Low Energy is Bluetooth 4.0 right? Problem is most android phones only go up to BT 2.1.

Comment: Yes, the latest iPhones have the hardware to support it, but not much else yet.